# Is it possible to create nested unit test using junit and mockito?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

For example:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ClientFormServiceTest {
    @Mock
    ClientFormService clientFormService;

    public class GetNewClientFormTest {
    @Mock
    protected ClientForm result;

    @Before
    public void given() {
        result = clientFormService.getNewForm();
    }

    @Test
    public void should_do_something() {
    }
}

public class CreateClientFormTest {
    @Mock
    protected ClientForm clientForm;

    @Before
    public void given() {
        clientFormService.createForm(clientForm);
    }

    @Test
    public void should_do_something() {
    }
}
```

}

This is what I want to do but I can't run the unit tests if are nested to a class.

Comment: You should clarify what you mean by "nested". Valid Java requires that each `public class` resides within its own *.java file of the same name. Therefore, your code example is asking for the test class `CreateClientFormTest` to run with Mockito when there is no `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` defined in that source file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm the author of a JUnit TestRunner, junit-nested, which I believe may do what you want:  https://github.com/avh4/junit-nested

However, from your example it's not clear why you need nested tests.  The typical reason to use them is to share setup behavior, but you should consider if having separate test classes is more appropriate.

In any case, here's how you can do it with junit-nested:  (Since `Nested` is a test runner, you'll have to use `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks()` instead of the Mockito test runner.)

```
import net.avh4.test.junit.Nested;

@RunWith(Nested.class)
public class ClientFormServiceTest {
    @Mock
    ClientFormService clientFormService;

    @Before
    public void given() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    public class GetNewClientFormTest {
        @Mock
        protected ClientForm result;

        @Before
        public void given() {
            MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
            result = clientFormService.getNewForm();
        }

        @Test
        public void should_do_something() {
        }
    }    

    public class CreateClientFormTest {
        @Mock
        protected ClientForm clientForm;

        @Before
        public void given() {
            MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
            clientFormService.createForm(clientForm);
        }

        @Test
        public void should_do_something() {
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why would you like to do that? If you mean to benefit from code reuse among many similar tests, you could come up with a base test class with common code and make test classes extend it.